# Hide div if, "0 results"?

Tags: php

My code works to a point. What I want is that when this if statement returns "0 results", the div doesn't show. At the moment it's only the result that doesn't show

```
<div class='<?php echo $hidemydiv ?>' >

<?php 

$sql = "SELECT type FROM bobby WHERE offer1='" . "$param_offer1" . "' AND u_id='" . "$param_uniqid" . "'";
$result = $link->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows < 2) {
  // output data of each row
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "" . $row["type"]. "<br>";
  }
} else {
  $hidemydiv = "hide";
}

?>

</div
```

Comment: Css: .hide{ display:none; }

Comment: Why not check for the number of results **before** printing that `<div>`?

Answer (score 1):

why not integrate it directly into php?

```
$query = $link->prepare('SELECT type FROM bobby WHERE offer1 = ? AND u_id = ?');
$query->bind_param('si', $param_offer1, $param_uniqid);
$query->execute();
$result = $query->get_result();

if ($result->num_rows < 2) {
    echo '<div>';
  while($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
    echo $row["type"]. "<br>";
  }
  echo '</div>';
}
```

I also took the liberty of changing the query thus preventing an inject attack
and I corrected from `fetch_assoc` to `fetch_array` being that you are using a `while`